# Удаление дубликатов в txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, txt

задача такая:
у меня есть `.txt` файл со ссылками. Каждый раз при запуске кода он парсит сайт и добавляет новые ссылки, но иногда попадаются уже использованные. Мне необходимо удалять все дублирующиеся ссылки + удалять их уникальные копии.

К примеру: мне нужно изменить `.txt` со ссылками

```
abc.ru
bac.ru
abc.ru
```

на выходе `.txt` файл должен содержать

```
bac.ru
```

Comment: Используйте set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое решение

```py
with open(".txt") as file:
    t_file = file.readlines()
    t_set = set(t_file)
    result = [i for i in t_set if t_file.count(i) == 1]

with open(".txt", "w") as file:
    file.write("\n".join(result))
```

Файл полностью перезаписывается новым содержимым, который исключает все дублирующие ссылки

Comment: Но есть нюанс: тут предполагается, что файл помещается в память)

Comment: @Qwertiy можно подробней? Не догоню

Comment: Ну надо прочитать весь файл и загрузить в оперативку. Ещё и в виде сета. Если файл не слишком большой, то отличный вариант. А если там миллионы строк, то не факт.

Comment: @Qwertiy то да, я думал, что-то не учёл. Так и задумывалось)

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать через конвертацию в список, который потом фильтруем по количеству упоминаний. Если имеем число отличное от единицы, то не включаем в новый список. Дальше `join()` в одну строку.

```
with open('www.txt') as file:
    rows = [row.strip() for row in file]
    filtered = [r for r in set(rows) if r and rows.count(r) == 1]
    filtered_string = '\n'.join(filtered)
```

Еще такой вариант в голову пришел после варианта *eri* с `Counter`:

```
with open('w.txt') as file:
    rows = [row.strip() for row in file]
    d = dict().fromkeys(rows, -1)
    for r in rows:
        d[r] += 1
    filtered = [k for k, v in d.items() if not v]
```

На выходе:

```
bac.ru
www.ru
```

Comment: есть классный https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: Тоже вариант. Как у всего этого со сложность?

Comment: а черт его знает)  помоему такая же

Comment: Что-то тут странное и неэффективное происходит...

Answer (score 0):

```
[e[0] for e in filter(
   lambda x: x[1]==1,
   collections.Counter(
       open('www.txt').readlines()
   ).most_common())
]
```